# Treat Mmap as volatile in Rust

Tags: rust

I am trying to monitor a binary file containing single 32 bit integer. I mapped the file into memory via `MmapMut` and read in a forever loop:

```
fn read(mmap: &MmapMut) {
    let mut i = u32::from_ne_bytes(mmap[0..4].try_into().unwrap());
    loop {
        let j = u32::from_ne_bytes(mmap[0..4].try_into().unwrap());
        if j != i {
          assert!(false); // this assert should fail, but it never does
          i = j;
        }
    }
}
```

However, compiler seems to optimise the loop away assuming neither `i` or `j` can ever change.

Is there a way to prevent this optimisation?

Comment: Which crate are you using?

Comment: You need to `msync` to see changes. Not sure how or if memmap exposes that. How about a filesystem watcher that wraps inotify etc.?

Comment: Try `MmapRaw` with `read_volatile()`.

Comment: @Ry- msync serves to ensure writing changes you've made back to the file system before munmap(): https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/msync.2.html This case should work without msync, but (as the OP correctly noted) requires volatile reads to disable Rust's normal optimizations.

Comment: But I agree with @Ry- that this usecase would probably be a good fit for a filesystem watcher.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I was using the old version of the mmap package, thanks to you I know to use memmap2:-) If you want to make this an answer, I will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`MmapRaw`](https://docs.rs/memmap2/latest/memmap2/struct.MmapRaw.html) with [`read_volatile()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ptr/fn.read_volatile.html).

```rust
fn read(mmap: &MmapRaw) {
    let mut i = unsafe { mmap.as_ptr().cast::<u32>().read_volatile() };
    loop {
        let j = unsafe { mmap.as_ptr().cast::<u32>().read_volatile() };
        if j != i {
          assert!(false);
          i = j;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Btw from my understanding Atomics are better option here than volatile.

Comment: @SamuelHapak Atomics and volatile do not overlap; there can be volatile atomic operations (although I think Rust does not have them). And atomic does not guarantee the compiler won't optimize the read out, although practically it doesn't.

Comment: I know the compiler is allowed to optimize atomics away under some special conditions, but I don’t think it can do so in the loop like this. I mean, you are supposed to be able to use atomics for safe thread synchronization, right?